# Is a standalone PC suitable for Hadoop and HBase learning?

Tags: nosql, hadoop

I'm interested in writing a web service using Hadoop and HBase (I found that I'm enjoying BigData-related thematics), but I want to ask you about one thing. If I install it on my PC, will this be enough to learn some basics of those technologies? Or it will be limited or even it will not work?

Comment: Hadoop is meant to be distributed across multiple machines. Hadoop can be installed on a single machine and spoof the other servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use it on a normal PC. It can been installed as psuedo-distributed on a single machine which is where it will multiple "servers" as separate processes.

Note, Apache says that the Windows installation distributed operation has not been well tested, but that should not be an issue if you are trying to learn the technologies.

Comment: I'm using Mac Os right now, so it won't be a problem. And, is Hadoop used in "single" mode?

Comment: You can, but the point of Hadoop is to take large amounts of data and distributed it across multiple machines. To get the most out of learning it, use it in psuedo-distributed mode

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any issue in configuring and running Hadoop and HBase on Mac. I have been doing this since quite sometime without any issue. You can start off with a pseudo-distributed cluster as DFord has specified.

That said, you have to be careful when switching to a proper, fully-distributed cluster. Using Hadoop on a single box for learning and testing is a lot different from working on a real cluster with several nodes. As the size of your cluster increases, more and more things start coming into picture.